# txt of strings into a cell array

Tags: string, matlab, file

I have a huge txt where in each row there are string separated with space. Each row may have different number of strings.

**Example:**

```
row1 str1 str2 str3 str4
row2 str1
row3 str1 str2 str3
```

I have tried to import this file not from command line into a cell array but it is extremely slow. Can we do that with command line? Will it be more fast?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To obtain all strings in a column cell array**

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
s = textscan(fid,'%s');
s = s{1};
```

For your example, this returns the following 11x1 cell array:

```
s = 
    'row1'
    'str1'
    'str2'
    'str3'
    'str4'
    'row2'
    'str1'
    'row3'
    'str1'
    'str2'
    'str3'
```

---

**To obtain all strings in a cell array of cell arrays, preserving numbers of columns**

```
A = importdata('tmp.txt');
s = cell(numel(A),1);
for n = 1:numel(A)
    s{n} = regexp(A{n}, ' ', 'split')
end
```

gives

```
s = 
    {1x5 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x4 cell}
```

such that

```
s{1}
ans = 
    'row1'    'str1'    'str2'    'str3'    'str4'
```

etc

Comment: Can we keep the initial form/dimensions of the matrix like in the example?

Comment: @Thoth In which format? Cell arrays have to be rectangular: same number of columns in each row